# MovieClip assets SWC from Flash inaccessible in Flash Builder using getDefinitionByName

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder, swc

I need to access MovieClips from an SWC created in Flash using getDefinitionByName() in Flash Builder. I know I have to add in the full package name whilst doing this, like so, with the package name being 'com.fusepump':

```
var className:String,
    assetName:String,
    obj:Class,
    i:uint;

for (i = 0; i < Config.ASSETS.length; i ++)
{
    className = String('com.fusepump.' + Config.ASSETS[i]);

    assetName = String(Config.ASSETS[i]).charAt(0).toLowerCase() + String(Config.ASSETS[i]).substr(1, String(Config.ASSETS[i]).length);

    obj = getDefinitionByName(className) as Class;

    _assets[assetName] = new obj();
}
```

The problem is that I don't seem to have any control of the package name in the SWC exported from Flash. In the Referenced Libraries directory the MovieClips are under Assets.swc/default package/Asset_1.abc - If I were able to add it to a named package the problem would be solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had such problems too. Try this solution [Flash Builder - How to build or include an SWC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333506/flash-builder-how-to-build-or-include-an-swc) you can build SWC in flashBuilder. The ones from flash ide are wierd to use in FlashBuilder.